# Powershell Implicit Remoting using JEA issue with MaxConcurrentUsers

Tags: windows, powershell, remoting

**Summary:**

I am running an implicit remoting server to centralize scripts which is accessible to 200 users. I am utilizing PowerShell 5 on the remote server and utilizing JEA. Modules and scripts are set up in the C:\Program Files directory.

**Issue:**

I am trying to increase the maximum concurrent users since I am getting an issue when there is only 5 users connecting. I checked netstat to see which users are on port 5985 and I can only seems to have a max of 5 users at a time.

**Solutions Attempted:**

1.
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/08874032-5b83-4cbc-81a3-fa16c44a993f/the-maximum-number-of-concurrent-shells-allowed-for-this-plugin-has-been-exceeded?forum=winserverpowershell

2.
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2010/05/02/configuring-wsman-limits/

**Side Notes:**

I am utilizing the microsoft.powershell psconfigfile to allow users to connect to the remote server.

Here are my WSMAN settings for remoting:

```
   WSManConfig: Microsoft.WSMan.Management\WSMan::localhost\Shell

Type            Name                           SourceOfValue   Value
----            ----                           -------------   -----
System.String   AllowRemoteShellAccess                         true
System.String   IdleTimeout                                    7200000
System.String   MaxConcurrentUsers                             100
System.String   MaxShellRunTime                                2147483647
System.String   MaxProcessesPerShell                           100
System.String   MaxMemoryPerShellMB                            1024
System.String   MaxShellsPerUser                               100
```

**Error Thrown:**

"Connecting to remote server x.x.x.x failed with the following error message : The WS-Management service cannot process the request. The maximum number of concurrent shells allowed for this plugin has been exceeded. Retry the request later or raise the Maximum Shells per Plugin quota."

**Verbose PowerShell Configuration Details:**

```
Architecture                  : 64
Filename                      : %windir%\system32\pwrshplugin.dll
ResourceUri                   : http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/microsoft.powershell
MaxConcurrentCommandsPerShell : 1000
Capability                    : {Shell}
xmlns                         : http://schemas.microsoft.com/wbem/wsman/1/config/PluginConfiguration
MaxConcurrentUsers            : 100
Name                          : microsoft.powershell
SupportsOptions               : true
ProcessIdleTimeoutSec         : 0
ExactMatch                    : False
RunAsUser                     :
RunAsVirtualAccountGroups     :
IdleTimeoutms                 : 7200000
RunAsVirtualAccount           : false
OutputBufferingMode           : Block
PSVersion                     : 5.0
SecurityDescriptorSddl        : Removed*
MaxShellsPerUser              : 100
AutoRestart                   : false
MaxShells                     : 100
MaxIdleTimeoutms              : 2147483647
Uri                           : http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/microsoft.powershell
SDKVersion                    : 2
XmlRenderingType              : text
RunAsPassword                 :
MaxProcessesPerShell          : 100
ParentResourceUri             : http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/microsoft.powershell
Enabled                       : true
UseSharedProcess              : false
MaxMemoryPerShellMB           : 1024
lang                          : en-US
```

Comment: What do you get for your JEA endpoints with `Get-PSSessionConfiguration | fl *` ?   Did you specify any transport options when creating the JEA endpoints?

Comment: @MatthewWetmore Hello Matthew, I updated the post with the PSsession Configuration details. And to answer your request, I added no transport options.

Comment: Which OS version and SKU?  (e.g. Server 2012 R2 Standard)

Answer (score 0):

After some digging around, I realized that these fixes worked... I simply needed to restart WINRM.... Thanks everyone for your support.

```
Restart-Service winrm
```